# Flutter: SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console, safetynet

When trying to run Firebase Phone Authentication through a Virtual Android Device am getting the following error messages;

```
E/zzbf    ( 6464): SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity.
I/zzmt    ( 6464): Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not available
W/System  ( 6464): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

1. Android Device Verification for the project is enabled through
   Google Cloud Console; https://i.stack.imgur.com/b43al.png
2. SHA-1 & SHA-256 is added to Firebase Project Settings; https://i.stack.imgur.com/aovkV.png
3. App level **build.gradle** has `implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"` & `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1`; https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfsqn.png

I have investigated similar StackOverflow topics and tried the possible solutions but no luck. Running on a physical Android Device it runs fine but in Virtual Device I can't get past captcha verification.

Also when checking the [SafetyNet documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet) I saw that it's deprecated and it will be replaced by [Play Integrity API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity).

1. Google Play Integrity API is enabled through Google Cloud Console; https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgnOm.png
2. App level **build.gradle** has `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'`; https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q29y.png

Nothing I have mentioned helped me fix the error messages, any suggestions ?

**UPDATE 1:**:
[image]
Found this place and added [Firebase App Check](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_app_check) dependency to my app, but does it actually have anything to do with it as my issue is still going on?

Comment: Hi! did you find a way around this issue? thx!

Comment: hey! just wanted to bring this to your attention in case you haven't seen it before. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3890

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this, might help,

1. Make sure to re-download the `google-services.json` whenever you change the SHA keys in the Firebase console.
2. Check if the android emulator (ADB) target supports Google Services

[image: Example ADB targets with Google play services]

Comment: I have tried with emulators that have Play Store support and with emulators that have only Google API support. No luck on both.

Comment: Well... Are you using SMS authentication?

Comment: If yes, that won't work on emulator

Comment: It used to work with my testing phone number introduced in Firebase Authentication system; https://i.imgur.com/zQ0U97u.png but now I get this issue.

Comment: You're using the same test number, right? Yeah, test phone numbers should work in the emulators though...